# Proving for a single input vs several inputs. Is there any difference?

Tags: provable-security, multiparty-computation, protocol-analysis

I am working on a new protocol for pattern matching. While defining the ideal functionality, it is possible to say:

1. Alice sends $p$ and Bob sends $T$ to the ideal functionality. i.e. searching for one pattern.
2. Alice sends $p_1,\dots,p_\lambda$ and Bob sends $T$ to the ideal functionality. i.e. searching for several patterns at once.

In both cases, Alice outputs $f(p_i,T)$ and Bob outputs nothing.

It is also possible to prove in both cases.

Is there any difference? Does the second definition add anything to security guaranties?

Comment: In #2 it is enforced that all $p_i$ are applied to the same $T$. In #1 there is no guarantee that Bob would send the same $T$ to every instance of the functionality.

Comment: @Mikero Just it and nothing else?

Comment: In #2 Alice cannot choose a pattern adaptively based on the result of previous patterns. This is possible in #1.